# Printed webpage looks different than in Google Chromes Print Preview

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I have been experiencing the weirdest problem, that I can't even begin to troubleshoot. It is important that the webpage in this project I am working is 100% printable. As you can see the signature field below and the note field (with the string "erererer") shows great in Google Chromes print preview but not when I actually print it out using the Chrome browser. In fact, the note field just prints out the border and nothing else (looks like a white empty div with a border) and the signature field prints out everything but the actual signature. When I use google chrome to save the document as a PDF and then print it out directly from the PDF everything prints perfect. When I use firefox to print, the signature area prints perfect, but the note problem remains of it only printing the outter border.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to begin to fix this or any input on why this may be happening.

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need accurate & reliable printability, going iText and PDF is a solution. You can render the page as PDF and it will show in the browser, and then print exactly as specified.

HTML is often inexact, has marks (page numbers etc) from the browser, and can be glitchy.

[iText](http://itextpdf.com/) (latest versions) are available open-source, or commercially. There's also an older version available free. See: [What is latest version of itext that is not AGPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321207/what-is-latest-version-of-itext-that-is-not-agpl)

As for your note field:  maybe there's something weird with backgrounds, non-standard styling? , or fonts that aren't present? Try making it a plain vanilla table.